# Php csrf token attack

Tags: php, csrf

Please clear my concept about CSRF attack.
In csrf we send token from hidden field i.e,

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf-token" value="5487987542hhui67868" />
```

and we submit form on session basis.
if attacker found my form and change hidden value and submit the form then he will be succeed.
how can I prevent form.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the CRSF token and if it's not valid, you can return an error to the user.

For example:

```
if($_POST['crsf-token'] == $_SESSION['crsf-token'] { 
      ... 
} else { 
     // error
}
```

Comment: if attacker hit with same session then it will be replay attack. i am using already your logic to prevent from replay-attack

Comment: unset $_SESSION['csrf-token'] at first correct validation ?